# Authorization Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, authorization, asp.net-membership

I want create a role for edit and assign it for who create the object FOO, for example:

FooController

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Edit(long id) {
    if (User.IsInRole("EDIT_ROLE_"+id)) {
        return View();
    } else
        return View("Index");
}

public ActionResult Create(Foo foo) {
    db.Foos.add(foo);
    db.SaveChanges();
    Roles.CreateRole("EDIT_ROLE_"+foo.FooID);
    Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Identity.Name, "EDIT_ROLE_"+foo.FooID);
    return View();
}
```

Is this the correct approach ? Is there some way to use `[Authorize(Roles = "EDIT_ROLE_//GET ID PARAMETER FROM ACTION//")]` instead `User.IsInRole`?

Comment: You can create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that will have access to the context and extract the id from the request.

Comment: That is what i need thx